# Clicking on an image for information to appear on wix

Tags: javascript

I am coding in JavaScrit in wix to make something that when I click on an element, it will unhide the other elements. Also, clicking another element will unhide another set of elements on the same position than the elements before. Clicking on another element will also hide the current unhidden ones to make space for the new unhidden ones. Clicking the same element will unhide the current ones as well.

`$w.onReady(function () { const element1 = $w('#imag32'); const element2 = $w('#image31');`

```
const contentSet1 = [$w('#box18'), $w('#box19'), $w('#text94'), $w('#image39')];
const contentSet2 = [$w('#box20'), $w('#box21'), $w('#text95'), $w('#image40')];

// Initially hide all content sets
contentSet1.forEach(content => content.hide());
contentSet2.forEach(content => content.hide());

// Function to hide all content sets except the one passed as an argument
function hideAllExcept(exceptContentSet) {
    const allContentSets = [contentSet1, contentSet2];
    allContentSets.forEach(contentSet => {
        if (contentSet !== exceptContentSet) {
            contentSet.forEach(content => content.hide());
        }
    });
}

// Toggle visibility of content when the associated element is clicked
element1.onClick(() => {
    console.log("Content 1 visibility: ", contentSet1[0].visible); // Check visibility
    if (contentSet1[0].visible) {
        contentSet1.forEach(content => content.hide('fade'));
    } else {
        hideAllExcept(contentSet1);
        contentSet1.forEach(content => content.show('fade'));
    }
});

element2.onClick(() => {
    console.log("Content 2 visibility: ", contentSet2[0].visible); // Check visibility
    if (contentSet2[0].visible) {
        contentSet2.forEach(content => content.hide('fade'));
    } else {
        hideAllExcept(contentSet2);
        contentSet2.forEach(content => content.show('fade'));
    }
});
```

});`

I tried this but the clickable elements are not working and the suppose to be unhidden elements are still there.

Comment: Can you create a reproducible demo of the problem you are facing and how it is not working, will be of help to suggest a proper solution for your problem..